# Printing in Color in HTBasic/Rocky Mountain BASIC in Windows XP

Tags: basic

Can someone help me understand this "Rocky Mountain BASIC" or "HTBasic" code?

I have to find out why the print functionality doesn't work anymore.

First, this line

```
PRINTER IS 26
```

I understand that the printer that we are going to use is "26" but what does 26 mean?

```
REPEAT
    IF LWC$(Imp$)="o" THEN
        PRINTER IS 26
        FOR I=0 TO VAL(Mesu$(0,5))
            FOR L=0 TO 6
                PRINT Mesu$(I,L)
            NEXT L
        NEXT I
    ELSE
        FOR L=0 TO 6
            PRINT TABXY(2,9+L);Mesu$(0,L)
        NEXT L
        FOR C=1 TO VAL(Mesu$(0,5))
            PRINT TABXY(20-36*(C>3)+(C-1)*12,8+8*(C>3)),"voie "&VAL$(C-1)
            FOR L=1 TO 7
                PRINT TABXY(20-36*(C>3)+(C-1)*12,L+8+8*(C>3)),Mesu$(C,L-1)
            NEXT L
        NEXT C
    END IF

    INPUT "SORTIE sur l'IMPRIMANTE  O/N ?",Imp$
UNTIL LWC$(Imp$)="n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“26” is one of the codes that specifies an output port for the PRINT statement. For example,

```
PRINTER IS CRT
PRINTER IS PRT
```

The letter codes correspond to number codes; `PRINTER IS CRT` is the same as `PRINTER IS 1`, for example, and PRT is the same as 701.

The codes that are likely to work for printing in this BASIC dialect, including 26, are:

> 26 701 9 15 19 23 24 25

I pulled this from an ancient document, [Using HP BASIC For Instrument Control: A Self-Study Course](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/hp/9000_basic/82302-90001_Using_HP_BASIC_for_Instrument_Control_Vol_1_Oct88.pdf), which you may find useful. (I suspect you meant HPBasic, not HTBasic, in your subject line?)

TABXY is a variant of the PRINT statement, for printing to specific locations on a CRT screen; the docs I’m seeing say that the XY is ignored if not printing to a CRT, but I wouldn’t be surprised if TABXY also worked on some plotters. The first two numbers would be the X and Y coordinates to begin displaying the text, with `TABXY(1, 1)` indicating the upper left corner, and the lower right corner depending on how many columns and rows the CRT has.

You may find the HP9000 series [BASIC Language Reference, Volume 1](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/hp/9000_basic/5.0/98613-90052_Basic_5.0_Language_Reference_Vol_1_Jan89.pdf) and [BASIC Language Reference, Volume 2](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/hp/9000_basic/5.0/98613-90052_Basic_5.0_Language_Reference_Vol_2_Aug88.pdf) useful.

LWC$ is just a lowercase function, to ensure that that whether the user inputs “O”, “N”, “o”, or “n” at the INPUT line, the program will respond correctly.

VAL converts a string to the number that that string represents. The string “3” would become the number 3, for example.

The variables Mesu$ is likely a two-dimensional array, with x from 0 to, judging from line 4, a variable amount contained in Mesu$(0, 5) and y from 0 to 6, judging from line 5.

Comment: Thank's for the explications.

I have an other problem right now is that I run this program on Windows XP and Windows 7, but on W7 it's only black and white and I want some colors 
I can't figure out how to do it. 

It works well on Windows XP...

Comment: And it is not HP Basic but a similar one, HTBASIC made byTransEra

Comment: Go ahead and add your new code to your question, or, if it's a separate question rather than a clarification of this question, make it a new question. I'm not familiar enough with the code (all I've done is glanced through the language reference) to know the answer, but someone else might, and they're more likely to see it if it is part of a question rather than part of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the line with PLOTTER IS 26 and we say that we want colors.

```
MAT Menu$=("")
DISP "envoi à l' imprimante .."
Menu$(1)="PLOTTER"
Menu$(2)="IMPRIMANTE COULEUR"
!Select(0,1,Tp,26,12,1)
IF Tp=1 THEN
     PLOTTER IS 705,"HPGL"
ELSE
     PLOTTER IS 26,"HPGL;PCL5;COLOR,1600",0,260,0,185
END IF
```